# this.$store.dispatch works but ...mapActions does not

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

Using vue 2 I'm trying to initialize data in vuex from a component before it loads. I can use the this.$store.dispatch and the action, along with its subsequent mutation, will run as expected from the created() function. If I call the same method in the created() function on the component using ...mapActions, the action and mutation in the module in the vuex store do not run as expected. I've looked at various ways to do this with namespacing the module (as it isn't the only module in this program), but I can't seem to get the method to run. It may be a timing in the lifecycle issue, but I'm not sure why created() wouldn't be appropriate. The addStage method is what I'm trying to have run to create the data in vuex to be displayed once the component that needs the data is loaded.

In a separate component (not shown here) I can use the ...mapActions helper by firing it from a button @click and it runs the addStage method from vuex just fine. What am I missing?

Component:

```html
<template>
    <div v-for="stage in getFlow.stages" :key="stage.id">
    <flowstage v-for="step in stage.steps" :key="step.id">
      <flowstep></flowstep>
    </flowstage>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex';

export default {
  name: 'flowbuildersub',
  created(){
    this.addStage;
    //this.$store.dispatch('flowbuilder/addStage');
    console.log("added stage");
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('flowbuilder', ['addStage']),
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters('flowbuilder', ['getFlow']),
  }        
}
</script>
```

Store:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import flowbuilder from './modules/flowbuilder.js';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    error: null,
    loading: false,
    information: null
  },
  getters: {
    getError(state) {
      return state.error;
    },
    getInformation(state) {
      return state.information;
    },
    getLoading(state) {
      return state.loading;
    },
  },
  mutations: {
    setInformation(state, payload) {
      state.information = payload
    },
    setError(state, payload) {
      state.error = payload
    },
    setLoading(state, payload) {
      state.loading = payload
    }
  },
  modules: {
    flowbuilder
  }
})
```

flowbuilder.js module:

```js
export const state = {
flow: {
    id: Math.ceil(Math.random()*100000000)+Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000),
    name: null,
    description: null,
    modifiedBy: null,
    stages: [],
  },
};

export const getters = {
  getFlow(state) {
      return state.flow;
  },
  getStages(state) {
      return state.flow.stages;
  },
};

export const actions = {
  addStage({ commit }) {
    let defaultStep = {
      id: 1,
      type: "Assign",
      data: null,
      description: null,
      subStep: null,
      required: null,
      selected: true,
    };

    let defaultStage = {
      id: 1,
      label: null,
      description: null,
      selected: false,
      steps: [
          defaultStep
      ],
    };
    console.log("made it here");
    commit('ADDSTAGE', defaultStage);
  },
};

export const mutations = {
  ADDSTAGE(state, defaultStage) {
    state.flow.stages.push(defaultStage);
    console.log("added stage");
  },
};

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations
};
```

Comment: `this.addStage;` - you didn't call the method

Comment: I've formatted your code into something more readable + removed useless parts.

Comment: @EstusFlask The this.addStage; line is in the created() method of the component. Any other ideas?

Comment: If you don't call a function in JS, it won't be called. It should be `this.addStage()`

Comment: @EstusFlask You are correct, wow can't believe I missed that today. More coffee for my future.